# Roots of a partially holomorphic function

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, implicit-function-theorem, weierstrass-preparation

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$, let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb C$ and let $f:\Omega\times U\rightarrow\mathbb C$ be a $C^\infty$ function which is holomorphic with respect to $\zeta$ on $U$. Let me assume that for some $(x_0,\zeta_0)\in \Omega\times U$,
$$
f(x_0,\zeta_0)=0,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial \zeta}(x_0,\zeta_0)\not=0.
$$
I want to show that there exists a smooth function $\lambda$ defined near $x_0$ such that $\lambda(x_0)=\zeta_0$ and
$$
f(x,\zeta)=e_0(x,\zeta)(\zeta-\lambda(x)),
$$
where $e_0$ is a  $C^\infty$ non-vanishing function defined near $(x_0,\zeta_0)$ which is holomorphic with respect to $\zeta$ and  $\lambda$ is a $C^\infty$ function defined near $x_0$.

This is obvious when $f$ is analytic by the holomorphic implicit function theorem.
However, with $f$ only $C^\infty$ with respect to $x$, I would like to avoid resorting to sophisticated arguments such as the Malgrange Preparation Theorem.

Comment: Just as in the case of holomorphic implicit function theorem the function lambda will be the integral over a circle in the zeta plane of zeta times the logarithmic derivative of f wrt zeta normalized suitably.